# Export all table data when filter is applied?

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, tables, filter, data-tables

If filters are applied to a table, should an export button export all the content in the table or just the content resulted of filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the user expectations and needs in the specific context of the application.

However, generally speaking, if a user has applied filters to a table, it is usually because they are interested in that specific subset of data. Therefore, when they choose to export the data, it would be logical to export only the filtered data, as that is what's currently displayed and relevant to them. This could potentially save them the time and effort it would take to manually remove unwanted data after export.

If you're worried about potential confusion or if users may also need to export the full unfiltered dataset at times, you could consider providing two options:

1. "Export All" to export all data, ignoring filters.
2. "Export Filtered" to export only the filtered data.